# generate header automatically with gcc or clang

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang, clang++

Given a source file `source.cpp` how I can generate the appropriate headers `source.hpp` ?

I'm under linux 64 bit and I would like to avoid writing the headers by hand to reduce the amount of time that I spend on writing code and limit the possible errors.

Comment: Who could tell what's "appropriate"? Usually you *start* with the class definitions and then have your toolchain generate the source file from that...

Comment: You could try: http://www.hwaci.com/sw/mkhdr/

Comment: @KerrekSB with appropriate I mean coherent. if my `foo()` returns a bool I wouldn't like to see `int foo()` in my header ... that's it.

Comment: @user2485710: You'd get a compiler error if you did that, though, so it's unlikely that such an error would introduce bugs. There are far more insidious ODR violations you can contrive with header magic, and *that* would be an interesting thing to analyze.

Comment: @KerrekSB ... but I enjoy being lazy ... damn compilation, now it's convenient to write my own headers, never thought about that. Out of curiosity, your ODR acronym is for ... ?

Comment: ODR: [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)

Comment: @Oswald thanks +a_lot_of_extra_char

Comment: You don't need forward declarations of functions if a function source is _before_ the sources of function calling it. Ex. if `main()` calls `foo()` then you just have to place the `foo()` source _before_ `main()` in your .cpp file. The same thing applies for classes since all the code _can_ be written inside the .h file - not saying this is good practice though.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen I'm planning to write a library, i need those headers _for the people out there_!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot generate appropriate headers from source files automatically, because there is no formal definition about what an *appropriate header* is. Especially, a tool that extracts declarations from a source file has no way of knowing whether a declaration should be private to a translation unit or shared among other translation units. In the first case, the declaration in the header would be IMHO inappropriate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832010/generate-header-automatically-with-gcc-or-clang#comment26026455_17832010

Comment: @user2485710 You've provided a link back to *this* question?

Comment: @trojanfoe it's a link to a comment

Comment: @user2485710 Oh, so it is.

Comment: Private declarations are idiomatically annotated with the `static` qualifier though, are they not? Meaning that it should, for appropriateness, suffice to assume declarations thus annotated are indeed "private", while those that aren't [thus annotated], are implied to be "public". Is there a reason to have such public objects which typically end up linked and embedded in the link product, while disallowing their use during compilation by hiding their corresponding declarations?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot really generate the code for your headers as there are things that are in the header that you cannot guess from the cpp file. The first things that come to my mind are the accessibility (public/protected/private) and inheritance.

What you can do however if you're trying to improve your workflow/productivity is using an IDE which has a lot a built in functionalities to help you edit the code. Creating a new class would for example create the header and cpp file, add an eventual inheritance, header guards, etc. It can help you renaming symbols to ease refactoring for example as well.

I personally use [QtCreator](http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator) which is free (as in free beer and free speech) but it's only a preference. I used Visual Studio as well with the [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) plugin (commercial), which provides some nice functionalities as well. I know that there are people that like Eclipse CDT, but I never really used it.

Choosing an IDE is only a matter of preference anyway ;)